# CORS error with DELETE

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've got a ReactJS/Redux app making calls to a .Net Core 2.1 Web Api; everything is local. My React app is http://localhost:3000 and my api is http://localhost:51666.

I had to enable CORS in the .Net app in order to make GET calls work, but no matter what I do, I cannot make a DELETE work.

The error is:

**EC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:3000' did not find 'http://localhost:3000' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'http://localhost:51666/api/logs/?globalIds[0]=26bea6e4-bf83-412b-89b9-f5241606801a'.**

BTW, I can take the output from the console.log statement below (and above) and execute it in Postman. It works perfectly. I also added 'mode' and 'headers' here trying to make it work.

My call looks like this:

```
export const deleteLogsByGlobalId = (globalIds) => {
    console.log(apiLogsPath + createGlobalIdQueryString(globalIds));
    fetch(apiLogsPath + createGlobalIdQueryString(globalIds),
        {
            method: 'DELETE',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:51666'
            },
        })
        .then(checkStatus)
        .catch((error) => console.log('Error from deleteLogsByGlobalId() => ' + error));
};
```

My Configure function in my api's Startup.cs looks like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            // app.UseCors(builder =>
            //             builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyHeader());

            // app.UseCors(builder =>
            //             builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000"));

            app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
        }

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

You'll see that I've tried some different things with the builder; even the AllowAnyOrigin doesn't work.

How do I fix this?

Help is appreciated.

V

Comment: If you check the Network tab of the Developer Tools, is it the DELETE request that fails or is it the OPTIONS request that fails?

Comment: @tholle Good question; the request gets a 200, but the OPTIONS gets a 204. I don't know what to do with that info, however.

Comment: It’s fine that the OPTIONS response is a 204. Browsers don’t care what specific 2xx code it is; that is, for the purposes of handling the preflight OPTIONS response, browsers treat a 204 (or any other code on the 200-209 range) exactly the same as they do a 200.

Comment: You should update the question to include the exact error message the browser logs in the devtools console when the DELETE request fails.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks; and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Here was the solution. Lose the headers in the fetch() call and define the allowable methods on the api.

Here's the working JavaScript:

```
export const deleteLogsByGlobalId = (globalIds) => {
    console.log(apiLogsPath + createGlobalIdQueryString(globalIds));
    fetch(apiLogsPath + createGlobalIdQueryString(globalIds),
        {
            method: 'DELETE',
        })
        .then(checkStatus)
        .catch((error) => console.log('Error from deleteLogsByGlobalId() => ' + error));
};
```

and the Configure function in the api:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseCors(builder =>
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                    .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE"));
    }

    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```